# spring applicationcontext two times initialization

Tags: spring

I have one spring applicationcontext xml file and in Main.java I used the below.

```
ApplicationContext ctx1 = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("bean.xml");
ApplicationContext ctx2 = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("bean.xml");

A a = (A)ctx1.getBean("a");
A b = (A)ctx2.getBean("a");
```

In this two instance of class **A** will be created because the container is loading the config file two times and the spring life cycle will be called twice.

Am I correct?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. The `ApplicationContext`s are independent and self-contained. Assuming your `a` bean is just a general bean

```
<bean name="a" class="com.example.A"/>
```

then the two variables `a` and `b` will be referencing distinct instances.